# Spring Hibernate: Save metadata to postgresql

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I am having trouble saving an object to postgresql using hibernate. My service is getting an object from the Repository, I am editing one property of the object and then saving it and then returning a DTO. Here is the Serice:

```
public NotificationDto markNotificationAsRead(Long recipientId, Long id){
        Notification notification = notificationRepository.findNotificationByUserByRecipientId_idAndId(recipientId, id);
        notification.setIsRead(true);
        notificationRepository.save(notification);
        return buildNotificationDto(notification);
    }
```

This is the Repository using hibernate

`Notification findNotificationByUserByRecipientId_idAndId(Long recipientId, Long id);`

The error I am getting when Hibernate is trying to update is:

ERROR: column "metadata" is of type json but expression is of type bytea

Is there an easy way to work around saving the metadata? TIA!

Comment: The service method `markNotificationAsRead` is not relevant to the problem. The name of the column is not relevant - we don't need it in the question. What counts is that column needs to be mapped as JSON - we need to see the entity and how you map the column in question.

Comment: Ended up changing the column type in the model and it works now thank you!

Comment: Let's show file `NotificationDto.java`